# How to set property undefined in nested array of nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
{
    _id: "xPBc4By8FemDwTPqH",
    friends: [{
        username: "michael",
        friendid: "154879",
        friendlist: [{
            randid: 54685,
            friendname: "john",
            illustrations: [{
                randid: 178432,
                image: "friend1.jpg"
            }, {
                randid: 545457,
                image: "friend2.jpg"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My database structure looks like this. I want to pull a particular image in the illustrations array. I tried this code:

```
Collections.user.update(
    { "friends.friendid": 154879} ,
    { $pull: { 'friends.$[].friendlist.$[].illustrations':  { "image": req.body.image  } } } ,
    function(err,result) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        else
            res.send("Deleted");
  })
```

This query is working but deletes the entire object instead of just deleting the filtered image. Another option I've tried is to set image = undefined, but it didn't work either.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you running?

Comment: Mongodb version 4.0

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Since version 3.6 MongoDB included the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) that I think it's exactly what you need:

```
Collections.user.update(
  { "friends.friendid": 154879 },
  { $pull: { "friends.$[elem1].friendlist.$[elem2].illustrations": { "image" : req.body.image } } },
  { arrayFilters: [
    { "elem1.friendlist.illustrations.image": req.body.image },
    { "elem2.illustrations.image": req.body.image }
  ]}
)
```

---

Original (and bad) answer:

I think this code will work:

```
Collections.user.update(
    { "friends.friendid": 154879 } ,
    { $pull: { "friends.friendlist.illustrations.image": req.body.image } } ,
    function(err,result) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else res.send("Deleted");
    }
);
```

Comment: If i tried like this i am getting this error. MongoError: Cannot use the part (friendlist) of (friends.friendlist.illustrations.image) to traverse the element. 

And also with out using randid how the image can pull in particular object in illustrations array.

Comment: You are right, this code doesn't work. I'm trying to fix it and I'll update my answer

Comment: Did you get any solution bro?

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer with it. I thought you would see it